# Is there a way to restrict a linux user in a Dockerfile to only be allowed to run some specific commands?

Tags: linux, bash, security, docker

I'm creating a Dockerfile with Fedora as base image. I created an user and I want this user to only be allowed to run basic commands (touch, echo, git).
I already tried modifying the sudoers file and pointing the PATH variable to another folder but none of these solutions have worked also I tried changing the permissions of the commands `chmod 700 /bin/ln` but this affects all the commands in `/bin` instead of that specific one, so the user cannot run any command after that. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Use a minimalist image instead and only install the commands you want the user to be able to run.

Comment: You might start with [`chroot`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)